# is this sentence correct with cut through?

Tags: grammar

I try make a sentence because i am not a native speaker. So I wonder is it right. I am very appreciate any suggestions.

"When I drive to my driveway. Suddenly, a cat cuts through a head of my car. I try to avoid him and my car was broken down"

Comment: Just a suggestion, but "ahead" is one word in Brit. Eng. usually. Except in horror writing.

Comment: I think you will get much better help in https://ell.stackexchange.com than you will here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cut through**. [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cut%20through)

v

> travel across or pass over

As in:

> "As I drive into my driveway, suddenly a cat **cuts through** ahead
>   of my car. I try to avoid him and my car stalls/stops/breaks down." or "and my car collides with the animal".

Comment: Shouldn't that be *ahead* ?

Comment: *stall* is almost certainly the wrong word here.

Comment: @Jeeped - noted and corrected

Comment: @PeterShor noted and edited

Comment: Actually, I think the OP means that his car hits something. Swerving doesn't usually make a car stall, but it can easily make it bump into something.

Comment: @PeterShor. I try to say, my his car hits the the dog :D.

Comment: oh ... you hit the animal!?

Comment: @lbf. No, I try to control the car for don't hit him and my car break downs.